# Why executor input for spark application running on amazon emr is showing more than the actual file size its processing?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, out-of-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, executor

I am running an amazon emr cluster with 20 spark applications having cluster configurations as 1 master node and 2 worker node as c5.24xlarge instance.
Giving 3 executors and one driver to each application.
But [spark web ui for executor input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKOMc.jpg) I can see input to executor is more than the file size to be processed, while in sql tab of spark web-ui, input is same as the file size only. [file input size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di0D6.jpg)
due to this, it's working so slow.

Answer (score 0):

Answer seems to be nothing technical but how input is shown on spark web ui for executors.
This input to the executors is nothing but the sum of inputs at the time of checkpoints set by spark itself.
Means it is nothing but the sum of all inputs shown in the total tasks list, as it is summary.
That's why spark sql tab was showing the right amount of input only.